# Database Logging

Tags: mysql, logging

Right now I have an automated donation system.

when they donate, the product id and their username is stored in a database, when they retreive their item, they're removed from the database

what i am thinking of doing is....
logging their username, how many times they've donated, and how much they've donated

this is the current logging

```
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO donation (username, time, productid, price, tickets) VALUES ('" . $user . "', '" . $date . "', '" . $prodid . "', " . $amount . ", " . $amountTickets . ");");
```

what i want it to do is
submit it to a new table, "amounts"
the username, 1, $ spent
and if they're already there
add +1 to the 2nd field (times donated), and $ spent + new $ spent

i'm not very intelligent when it comes to mysql so any help would be appreciated

**SUMMARY**
i want a sql query that will make a new field in a table called (amounts)
if the field already exists, add onto the fields in it
fields:
username, times donated, amount donated

basically if someone named frank donates $10

frank, 1, 10

if frank donates another 20

frank, 2, 30

if joe donates 15 after that

frank, 2, 30

joe, 1, 15

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like home work....

```
select `username`, count(`username`), sum(`price`) as `amounts`
from donation
group by username
```

Pardon my quoting may be wrong as I usually use postgres which has different quoting to mysql. I suggest that you read the online manuals regarding aggregate functions in your chosen database.

Comment: so it'd look like this?

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO amounts (username, amounts, price) VALUES ('" . count($user) . "', " . ??? . ", " . sum($amount) . ");");

Comment: no, use the query to extract the summarized data from donation. I am assuming that your donation table records the history of donation events. So, use your insert statement from the question each time you have a donation, and use something like my query each time you need to summarize. I could be making some incorrect assumptions on you requirements so I may be using the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you retain the data from the donation table and just add an additional column lets say status and the value is UNCLAIMED or CLAIMED.  Once the user claimed the items you just need to update their status as CLAIMED.

To show unclaimed donation

```
SELECT * FROM donation WHERE status = 'UNCLAIMED';
```

To retrieve users donation

```
SELECT username, count(username),sum(amount) FROM table WHERE status = 'CLAIMED' GROUP BY username
```